# Not able to browse multidimensional cube hosted on analysis server

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I have built and deployed and processed multidimensional cube on analysis server.
But while browsing cube in sql server management studio or excel is not fetching any results and going to not responding state

Answer (score 1):

Click the Reconnect icon on the toolbar of the designer as next and then refresh:

[Reconnect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qak96.png)

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/analysis-services/multidimensional-tutorial/lesson-2-6-browsing-the-cube?view=asallproducts-allversions#to-browse-the-deployed-cube